# Rewriting a URL to remove certain characters

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I need to rewrite some blog URLs to remove certain characters. These are the along the lines of "a556" (a is always present, the numbers are always 3 digits and are random). This is proceeded by either a single or double hyphen, which I also need to remove.

These need to redirect from:

> [domain]/blog/[article_name]-a556

or

> [domain]/blog/[article_name]--a556

To

> [domain]/blog/[article_name_with_characters_removed]

I *think* the regex to detect the text to be removed is:

```
([-]{1,2}a[0-9])\w+
```

But I don't know how to put this into a Rewrite rule.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You want to *redirect* those old URLs to new URLs? Or you want to generally make your URLs appear in that new format?

Comment: Tip: These kinds of vanity URLs are easy to exploit, as malicious users can forge links that look like `[domain]/blog/something-really-nasty-and-offensive-a556`. Better you check the vanity part as well, instead of throwing it away.

Comment: @Tomalak What would somebody gain from that...?

Comment: Correct, I was going to redirect, but I think otajor's answer below should solve the problem. Thanks for the responses, though, much appreciated.

Comment: @deceze Well, what do trolls gain from their activities? I remember a case quite a while ago that generated some outrage, so I put unchecked vanity URLs on my mental "don't"-list, that's all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for a function to process your old URLs into new ones? Something like this should do the trick, if you have an array of URLs:

```
var processedURLs = oldURLs.map(function(url) {
  return url.replace(/[-]{1,2}a[0-9]+/, '');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)-{1,2}a\d{3}(.*) $1$2 [R]
```

Answer (score -1):

This rewrite rule could does the trick:

```
blog/(.+[a-zA-Z0-9])-+a[0-9]+      blog/$1
```

You can simplify [a-zA-Z0-9] removing all characters ranges that can't appear in the end of the articles name slug (ie [a-z0-9] or [a-z]).